# Php parse_ini_file duplicate keys

Tags: php, parsing

I want to use parse_ini_file function, however dont know how to do this with duplicate keys like below.Is it possible with this function?

```
[test]
1=x
1=y
2=z
......
```

Thanks

Comment: yes , it not works

Comment: well, there is your answer: "no, it is not possbile with this function"

Comment: It is not possible with [parse_ini_file][1] to get duplicate Indicies,
duplicate Values are possible.


A INI-File consist of Key-Value-Pairs and `parse_ini_file` returns an associative array and duplicate array-keys get overwritten.   


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: This is not useful in any way, unless you use it in a loop. I wanted to create ini file with data to be shown in menu and I put element name (a) as section name. When I placed second one, it did not work... But. to solve it, I also put a space and number after it (a 1, a 2...). It worked!

Comment: @user6618536 Not sure if you are still looking for a solution but check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820008/2191572