# Maintain all values of duplicate keys when parsing .ini file

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I have a `php.ini` file which contains the following lines:

```
; ...settings

extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci

; settings...
```

So I do this:

```
var_dump( parse_ini_file( '/path/to/php.ini' )[ 'extension' ] );
```

But all I get is `string(7) "pdo_oci"` so it looks like the parse simply maintains the final value which `extension` was set to.

Is there a way to make the `extension` key return an array instead?

I understand that PHP's internals probably use a dedicated parser to explicitly handle this situation so that extensions load properly but that does not help me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the keys of the ini file become the keys to the array, the values are overridden. I came up with my own function.

**The code:**

```
function my_parse_ini($file){
    $arr = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $parsed = parse_ini_string($line);
            if(empty($parsed)){ continue; }
            $key = key($parsed);
            if(isset($arr[$key])){
                if(!is_array($arr[$key])){
                    $tmp = $arr[$key];
                    $arr[$key] = array($tmp);
                }
                $arr[$key][] = $parsed[$key];
            }else{
                $arr[$key] = $parsed[$key];
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
        return $arr;
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    } 
}
```

Call it passing the file to be parsed, like so:

```
$parsed = my_parse_ini('/path/to/php.ini');
```

---

**The result:** (`$parsed`)

For a file containing

```
; ...settings

extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci

foo=test
bar=ok
foo=teste1
; settings...
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [extension] => Array
        (
            [0] => pdo_mysql
            [1] => pdo_oci
        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => teste1
        )

    [bar] => ok
)
```

Comment: I've taken a look at your code and it looks promising but I have to go to a meeting so I will test it out later. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I've tested it locally, but it will be better after your test. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Finally got a chance to test this and I love it, thanks!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm glad I was of help :)